# heroku works locally but not in server shows "ERROR: connecting to localhost:5037"

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku

In my project I am referring to "pure python ADB client" which is working fine locally. But after deployment, when I try to run the application using `Heroku open` it shows

> ERROR: Connecting to localhost:5037 [Errno 111] Connection refused.
>
> Is adb running on your computer?

I tried with 127.0.0.1 but it still shows an error.

```
def getConnected_devices(request):
    """Connect the devices via usb or WIFI through adb and get the device details dynamically and update the status of device"""


    client = AdbClient(host="localhost", port=5037)
    devices = client.devices()
```

usb connected device should be recognized properly in the heroku cloud.

Comment: What? How could you plug your USB device in to a virtual server in the cloud? That makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

There is a misunderstanding here of some type. Not totally sure where.

The cloud is an entirely different computer from your own local computer. `localhost` refers to your own machine. Heroku’s computer is a machine probably a thousand kilometres away from you.

Unless you went to the Heroku data warehouse and plugged a USB into the server hosting your Django implementation, your code will not work as the computer is searching for something physically attached to that machine. And that assumes you bought non-virtualized services.

If you want to read data from a USB connected device to the cloud, you are going to either need to significantly rethink your implementation or use your own local machine to do the hosting.

Consider a tool like Ngrok. It allows you to easily host a Django server on your home computer and then access the data via the internet. It’s not a production suitable solution, but I’d you needs are modest, it is a simple and cheap way to do the job.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. But one more question. Say for ex my application running in heroku local in particular network. Will it possible, other can access the instance with different network. However, it's working fine in same network.